# Как в node.js + express вызывать рендер с передачей параметров полученных при прослушивании события?

Tags: node.js, express

Здравствуйте, вынес реализацию метода, который работает с ожиданием события в отдельный модуль.
Во время рендеринга страницы идет обращение к этому методу за получением параметров. Параметры не возвращаются. Как правильно организовать эту задачу в моем случае?

index.js

```
   var vk = require('./lib/vk.js');
    app.get('/vk', function(req, res) {
        res.render('home',{
                    vk: vk.getMessages('wall.get', {'owner_id' : 456475864535})});
    });
```

vk.js

```
    var VK = require('vksdk');

    var vk = new VK({
        'appId': 5364746354,
        'appSecret': 'fxgdhfdfs',
        'language': 'ru'
    });

exports.getMessages = function (req,params) {
    vk.setSecureRequests(true);
    vk.request(req,params);


    vk.on('done:wall.get', function (_o) {
        return "privet"; // даже это не выводит
        console.log(JSON.stringify(_o, null, 4));
        return _o;
    });
};
```

Comment: Функция vk.getMessages() у Вас ничего не возвращает, хотя бы потому, что в ней банально нет `return` Однако на самом деле, проблема в асинхронности: у Вас res.render вызывается раньше, чем приходит ответ на запрос vk.request. Вам надо передавать callback в `getMessages`, вызывать его внутри обработчика `done:wall.get`, и уже в нем вызывать `res.render()`

Comment: Да, стоило самому подумать, решил что есть какое то общепринятое решение и конструкция именно для такого случая.

Comment: Общепринятое решение — это как раз коллбэки и есть. :) Ну или же промисы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий вариант.
index.js

```
app.get('/vk', function(req, res) {
        vk.getMessages('wall.get', {'owner_id' : 34245436756},res);
});
```

vk.js

```
exports.getMessages = function (req, params, res) {
    vk.setSecureRequests(true);
    vk.request(req, params);

    vk.on('done:wall.get', function (_o) {
        res.render('home', {vk: JSON.stringify(_o, null, 4)});
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(_o, null, 4));
    });
};
```